# Best place for where i can get a deep study on android

Tags: android

Please suggest me the best place from where i can study android. I want to get more information on android classes, methods etc. I was looking for MenuItems in google i found how to use it. But i really need to know how to declare what are the parameter a deep study. Can anybody help me to get a best guide from where i can understand all the methods and using examples for using it. This might me very helpful for me.

Comment: The best place on stackoverflow is the [android tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29

Answer (score 2):

[Developer.android](http://developer.android.com)

Has everything you need

Answer (score 0):

[Complete Android Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)

Here you can get details how to declare and what are the uses of the android methods classes etc. in Training section and About Parameters ant others things you can refer to Reference Section.hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Google developed set of [Trainings](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) for developers who only start working on Android framework.

Also you can check this [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html). It can give full information about components, lifecycles and Android best practices.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mybringback.com/

Provide a good tutorial with videos for beginners and having different level of courses to study for free.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/

Also provide a very good guidance to learn android and mobile applications. But after some level it is paid.